# How to display google charts on every post

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

When I add google chart in my while loop it only shows up once at the very first post. I would like to show the google chart next to every post.

Unfortunately it doesn't work even though it's added in the while loop.

Here is my code:

```
            <div id="wrapper">

        <?php include "includes/navigation.php"; ?>
        <?php include "../includes/functions.php"; ?>

        <div id="page-wrapper">

            <div class="container-fluid">

                <!-- Page Heading -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">
                            Statistieken
                            <small><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></small>
                        </h1>

                        <!-- week nav -->
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Week 1</a></li>
                          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Week 2</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Week 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- einde week nav -->


                        <!-- logboek van user -->

                        <?php 


                        $the_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

                        $query = "SELECT * FROM logboek WHERE logboek_user = $the_user_id LIMIT 3 ";
                        $select_logboek_user = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                        confirmQuery($select_logboek_user);

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_logboek_user)){

                            $logboek_image = $row['logboek_image'];
                            $logboek_title = $row['logboek_title'];
                            $logboek_content = $row['logboek_content'];
                            $logboek_date = $row['logboek_date'];
                            $logboek_time = $row['logboek_time'];
                            $logboek_studielastuur = $row['logboek_studielastuur'];


                        ?>

                         <?php

                            echo $logboek_studielastuur;

                            ?>


                          <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          pieHole: 0.4,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>


                      <!-- 2 colum logboek -->    
                      <div class="row">

                          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
                              <?php echo '<div id="donutchart" style="width: auto; height: auto;"></div>'; ?>   
                          </div>


                          <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-3">
                              <img src="images/<?php echo $logboek_image ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                              <h3 class="text-center"><?php echo $logboek_title; ?></h3>
                              <small><?php echo $logboek_date; ?></small>
                              <small><?php echo $logboek_time; ?></small>
                              <p><?php echo $logboek_content; ?></p>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- einde 2 colum logboek -->    






<!-- full width logboek
                        <h3 class="text-center"><?php echo $logboek_title; ?></h3>
                        <img src="images/<?php echo $logboek_image ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                        <small><?php echo $logboek_date; ?></small>
                        <small><?php echo $logboek_time; ?></small>
                        <p><?php echo $logboek_content; ?></p>
-->

                        <?php } ?>

                        <!-- einde logboek user -->







                        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
                          <div class="container">
                               <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                    <li role="presentation"><a href="aanwezigheid.php"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Aanwezigheid</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Status</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="statistieken.php?source=view_all_statistieken"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i> Statistieken</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation"><a href="statistieken.php?source=add_logboek"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Logboek</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation"><a href="statistieken.php?source=add_logboek"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Rooster</a></li>

                    </div>
                              </nav>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->

        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
<?php include "includes/footer.php"; ?>
```

Here is an image description:

[image]

I really appreciate your help!

Kind Regards,
Kevin.

Comment: It is hard to help someone when they post huge splats of code... Removing the useless parts would definitely help you get help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `getElementById` to target where to put the donut charts. The problem is that there should be only one element with the same ID, they should be unique! Acknowledging this rule, the browser stops looking for elements once it finds the first one.

You should use a very unique ID per post and it will work...

As your code is too large, I'll reproduce a small example:

```
<?PHP
    foreach($posts as $post){
        echo '<div class="donutchart" id="donutchart_'.$post['id'].'"></div>';
        ?>
        <script>
            var data = theGraphData;
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart_<?=$post['id']?>'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        </script>
    }
?>
```

Basically, you call the javascript on the right ID at every part... There are also a couple other ways to do so, like adding the data directly on an element and after everything is drawn the javascript looks for them and do the work. Also, make sure you do not load the google API every foreach incrementation...

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? Because I have an unique id for every post (the_post_id)

Comment: I would have edited your code but it is way too long... I'll show you the base

Comment: he means each element must have a unique id, and you are getting the element by id, so it only picks one, use `getElementsByClassName` instead of id

Comment: @JEES actually even that wouldn't work as he is injecting the javascript in the foreach iterations. So the donuts would all look the same, like the last element.